# Delphi = Pascal? Resources for Learning?

Tags: delphi, resources, pascal

Well, I am new to Delphi and really offline programming in general (other than the standard C++) and recently acquired a copy of Delphi and was kind of interested in starting with it. I read somewhere that it uses Pascal but I was confused on if it used Pascal, as in it was programmed with it, or if it used Pascal as in the language you code in it. Either way, I was wondering if anyone had any good resources to start learning. Either books or articles/forums online would be splendid. This is a neat little community here so I plan on utilizing this.

Comment: It should be Delphi == Pascal.

Comment: lol wasn't sure about which one to use :)

Comment: In Pascal, '=' is the equality test, not '=='

Comment: And Delphi>Pascal would be way better, as the language is several times larger.  It's like C++>C.

Comment: Except the things that Delphi added to its base language aren't defective. ;)

Comment: Lonestar, you've really asked two questions. One is about what the product really is, and the other is about resources to learn it. Don't combine them into a single post. Ask them separately so that the answers can be more focused (and so that you can get more points by people voting on two questions instead of one).

Comment: Mason: I'm not so sure if Delphi did that so clean either. Slowly the language is getting unwieldy large. I think the problem with C++ is more that the base language was so conceptually limited (no module, preprocessor etc) that extending it in the same spirit and backwards compat was too hard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Delphi is a pascal-based object-oriented programming language.  It's also a product, a large part of which has been programmed using the Delphi language.

Here are some excellent SO questions with answers that contain fantastic suggestions for learning Delphi:

- [Learning Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222/learning-delphi)
- [Books about the Delphi language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348308/what-book-you-advise-me-to-read-about-delphi-language-not-vcl-winapi-etc)
- [What's the best Delphi book for a newbie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647/whats-the-best-delphi-book-for-a-newbie)
- [Delphi tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814648/delphi-what-are-your-dos-and-donts-tips)

Many of those SO answers contain useful links, including many of the ones provided by others here, along with comments (and SO votes) to help you prioritize them.

Answer (score 12):

http://www.marcocantu.com/EPascal/default.htm

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/

http://delphi.about.com/

http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/

Comment: +1 for Delphi Basics. Great site for looking at the fundamentals of the language. Also very handy as a replacement for the help in Delphi since in the later versions of Delphi its slow, ponderous and an unsearchable pile of junk. It was great in Delphi 5 & 6.

Answer (score 8):

Delphi refers to both a programming language built around an object-oriented evolution of Pascal known as Object Pascal, and its associated RAD IDE development environment.  That's a pretty formal definition, though, and you can generally use "Delphi" and "Object Pascal" interchangeably.

We've got a nice, strong Delphi representation here on StackOverflow for asking questions.  In fact, if your question is advanced enough, it's not uncommon to see it get answered by various high-level Delphi team members.  You can also go to the official CodeGear (the company that makes Dephi) forums at http://forums.codegear.com

Answer (score 7):

I think websites are pretty much covered in previous answers ([Delphi Basics](http://delphibasics.co.uk/) would be my suggestion) so here's a couple of books:

- [Delphi in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926592/). Its is quite old, but it's a good reference to start with.
- [Borland® Delphi™ 6 Developer's Guide](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0672321157). Again, an old book, but packed with info.

For something more up to date (I've not read these personally), try:

- [Delphi XE Starter Essentials](http://www.lulu.com/shop/bob-swart/delphi-xe-starter-essentials/paperback/product-14723094.html) by [Dr. Bob](http://www.drbob42.com/).

He also has [a full section of books on Lulu](http://www.lulu.com/spotlight/drbob42).

Answer (score 6):

You should also check out [Marco Cantu's site](http://www.marcocantu.com/), and look for the Essential Pascal and Essential Delphi books. The first one is a free download.

Comment: And if you're in a good used book store, have a look for Marco's giant Delphi tomes.

Answer (score 5):

**Delphi Basics**
[www.delphibasics.co.uk](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk)
**Best for all delphi beginners

**VCL Sources**
Best way to learn how to really program in delphi

**Mastering Delphi** by *Marco Cantu* 
[www.marcocantu.com](http://www.marcocantu.com)

**Delphi 3000** 
http://www.delphi3000.com/ 
For learning to do things practically

Comment: Is delphi3000.com a good site? Everytime I get it AVG says there is a SQL Injection Exploit.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Beginning Delphi](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Beginning_Delphi) and [Delphi Video](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Videos) wiki pages.

The [3DBuzz](http://www.3dbuzz.com/vbforum/sv_home.php) site has changed a little and all of their Delphi video tutorials are available from the front page.

On Embarcadero's [Developer Network site](http://edn.embarcadero.com/), under the Resources menu, there are links to all kinds of audio and video content.  Note that you can filter it by product.

Comment: 3DBuzz only has 2 tutorials sadly. One video is 40 minutes with 30 of that talking about how to get Turbo Delphi (which requires .NET 1.1...very outdated and known compatibility issues)

Comment: I think you missed some. There are 3 sets of tutorials under the Delphi category, with 9 videos in total. The second and third ones are 71 and 153 minutes respectively. 

Turbo Delphi is based on Delphi 2006 Pro, but the tutorials apply equally well to newer (and even older) versions.

Comment: Ahh, yheah. I did miss the others. They junp pretty quick into an mp3 player. Not exactly something for a beginner. I'll watch them and see though. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Again, take a closer look. An MP3 player might sound advanced, but they spend a lot of time on the basics.  I think you'll be happy with the technical level.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen a Pascal Language resource as perfect as the Delphi help itself! I hadn't heard about Pascal before I got a copy of Delphi. I learned Pascal from Delphi's help system (Object Pascal Reference).

You will have an intermediate level understanding of Pascal Language from Delphi help. **Learn the real world usage of language constructs from VCL/RTL source code (especially sysutils.pas, system.pas, etc..)**!

Comment: You must have a D6/D7 version :_)

Answer (score 2):

For quick reference, I often use the FPC docs. Multiple format (html,pdf,chm), and more examples.

Of course it requires you to look out for minor compatibilities, but looking at an alternate wording it can be useful:   http://www.freepascal.org/docs.html or the CHM versions at http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/doc-chm.zip

However the *absolutely* best source was the D7 dead-tree manuals (language and developer guide), which I read back to back several times. People assure me the current help has all that and more, but somehow I'm unable to access it as easily as then.