# Delphi Programming Manual

Tags: delphi, x86, reverse-engineering

I am trying to find a Delphi Programming Manual where I can see a description of what each function does, its arguments, and return values. Does anyone know where I can find one? Something similar to [Microsoft's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Just so you know, I have never EVER programmed Delphi before and I know absolutely nothing about it (and I don't have the time to learn it).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at http://delphibasics.co.uk ?

Comment: Hopefully, you will have time to delve into Delphi from now on :-)

Comment: If you're going to reverse-engineer Delphi applications you'll have a much harder time to find documentation about calls. Most of the library is an object-oriented one, so it's much more like reversing C++ than plain C. And it has its own calling conventions and data types.

Comment: The local help files which are in a Microsoft-specific documentation format, that ships with the product is the most similar thing to Microsoft's MSDN API docs.  The online wiki and online docs are very similar in content to the local help files, but the "doc wiki" is slightly more recently edited.

Answer (score 14):

The official site for Delphi documentation is the Embarcadero Documentation Wikiwhich can be found in this location [`Online Help for Delphi® XE2 and C++Builder® XE2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/), this is the *equivalent* to the MSDN of Microsoft. if you are looking for tutorials check this question [`Delphi = Pascal? Resources for Learning?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149238/delphi-pascal-resources-for-learning)

Comment: +1, @Fran, about the online help, check the [`Delphi tag`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/delphi/info) itself, 3 latest versions of online help are linked there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One of the better resources for this is to find the Windows based help files from an earlier version. So much better and more informative than the current help (but not perfect!). I have the Delphi 6 Files loaded in an easily accessible folder for reference. Or scour ebay for older printed Manuals. The basic VCL and windows API calls have not changed **that** much over the years.

Comment: +1 printed manuals. If you are in a hurry, ploughing through them is a very good time-results tradeoff. Assuming you are knowledgable in a similar language like C++.

Comment: No longer true.  Delphi 6/7 help files were better than the help in the 2005-2010 era, but the Delphi XE and XE2 help files are far better, more complete, and better indexed than any other delphi version ever. Point taken about having paper manuals though. I had the Delphi 6 paper manuals at one time, and I find it helpful to have the printed versions of ANY new material I'm learning.

Comment: Can't comment on XE versions but I'll take your word for it. I am on 2009 and the help is not very good or informative.

Answer (score 1):

If you like books better than reading online. http://www.lulu.com/shop/bob-swart/delphi-xe-development-essentials/paperback/product-13211362.html